# How to query active directory for Getting Shared Calendar items?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to develop an application which shows available meeting rooms across a particular time frame in a month/year.

Is using Active directory will be a good idea for this, or should I use Outlook dlls for the same?

Any Help or Code samples will be much appreciated.

Comment: Since when or how does AD save the meeting rooms, what kind of object is that?

Comment: what is the best method for doing this? where do I get the Shared calendar details ?